# Sphinx: OR operator in sphinxql

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

I have a date field (Start_date) in my database that have indexed it in sphinx as sql_field_string and it's format is like: 2000-12-12.
When I want to search on that field I submit a query like this:

```
select * from all where match ('@Start_date 2000-12-12');
```

and it's working, but I'm having trouble when **submitting a query with OR** operator like this that does not return any results while in fact there are many results:

```
select * from all where match ('@Start_date 2000-12-12 | 1999-12-12');
```

And when I use Parentheses for values, problem is fixed!

```
select * from all where match ('@Start_date (2000-12-12) | (1999-12-12)');
```

Why is this happening ?

( I have added '-' character to my charset_table).

from sphinx.conf file:

```
dict = crc
min_infix_length=3
```

Comment: Did you rebuild the index (and allow searchd to load it!) after adding - to charset_table?

Comment: Yes. Should I use unicode of '-' character or '-' itself when changing charset_table value? I used this value: charset_table = -, 1..9, english

Comment: well in theory just a vanila - should be ok, it can't be misinterpreted as syntax (like comma and dot), but putting U+2D would be safer.

Comment: But it might just be that - is also extended syntax operator, so maybe its you need to escape it. `match('@Start_date 2000\\-12\\-12 | 1999\\-12\\-12');` - the double slash, need to escape it as part of the SQL string too!)

Comment: Escaping didn't solve the problem and results are not same as when using parentheses. Very strange!

Comment: It also works when I use " character instead of parentheses. Do you have any idea why is this happening? Does the searcher ignore '-' character?

Comment: not 'ignore' as such, but think that because it search operator makes it more complicated (it might get misinpretered sometimes)